# Are SPL-Token similar to ERC20?

Tags: spl-token

Are SPL-Token to Solana, what erc20 tokens are to ethereum? If so what are solana's concept corresponding to things like ERC-721 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPL tokens are to Solana what ERC tokens are to Ethereum. The difference is that while precise standards exist to distinguish between different types of tokens on Ethereum, the same does not exist on Solana.

On Ethereum a usual token adheres to the ERC-20 standard while an nft is an ERC-721 token. On Solana both tokens would simply be considered SPL tokens.

On Ethereum to create a nft you create a token that fits the ERC-721 standard and thus is different from a usual token. On Solana you create an SPL token that's just like any other token, make its supply limited, and attach metadata accounts that contain its information to it.

Answer (score 1):

in Ethereum, you have `ERC20 Tokens` (Token Mint). In Solana, `SPL Tokens`

In Ethereum, you don't have `Token Accounts`, you can send any `token` to anyone.
In Solana, a `Token Account` is an account that holds `SPL Tokens`. You need to have a `Token Account` for that `SPL Token` if you wanna hold that `SPL Token`.
You send `SPL Tokens` to `Token Account`

In Ethereum, you don't have a `Token Program`. Rather it's done implicitly.
In Solana, `Token Program` allows the transfer of `SPL Tokens` between `Token Accounts`. It **needs** to be called in order to transfer the `SPL Tokens`.

`Token Program ID` is the address of the `Token Program`. e.g. ["TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"](https://explorer.solana.com/address/TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)